# Can't access my API after I made my app PWA

Tags: reactjs, express, progressive-web-apps, manifest, manifest.json

I have a react app and an express.js server running on my shared host.

Before I convert my app to a PWA I would access my API at `/api` of my website URL.

But after that I get this error and I don't get any response from API just browser tries to load my loader image:

I use Vite for development.

[image]

I managed to convert my app to PWA with:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { VitePWA } from "vite-plugin-pwa";

const manifestForPlugin = {
    registerType: "prompt",
    includeAssets: ["favicon.ico", "apple-touch-icon.png", "masked-icon.svg"],
    manifest: {
        name: "Alibot.ir",
        short_name: "Alibot",
        description: "My personal website.",
        icons: [
            {
                src: "/android-chrome-192x192.png",
                sizes: "192x192",
                type: "image/png",
            },
            {
                src: "/android-chrome-512x512.png",
                sizes: "512x512",
                type: "image/png",
            },
            {
                src: "/apple-touch-icon.png",
                sizes: "180x180",
                type: "image/png",
                purpose: "apple touch icon",
            },
            {
                src: "/maskable_icon.png",
                sizes: "225x225",
                type: "image/png",
                purpose: "any maskable",
            },
        ],
        theme_color: "#171717",
        background_color: "#e8ebf2",
        display: "standalone",
        scope: "/",
        start_url: "/",
        orientation: "portrait",
    },
};
// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    base: "./",
    plugins: [react(), VitePWA(manifestForPlugin)],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check cache storage in browser's dev tools (application tab). Maybe your API urls are cached in cache storage...

In fact, you must describe more about your codes. How do you convert your app to PWA?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion I cleared the cache but the problem persists. I just added the way I converted my app to PWA.